# React this doesn't work sometimes in the callback of setState

Tags: javascript, reactjs, setstate

Suppose

```
callback = () => { ... }
```

When should I use

```
this.setState({...}, this.callback);
```

and when should I use

```
this.setState({...}, () => { this.callback(); });
```

To ensure the **this** is still valid within the `this.callback` method.

Is there some basic rules we should follow out there?

Comment: good question. I look forward to the answer,  I suspect the answer will have to do with what the callback function is doing, for instance if it is calling another method

Answer (score 1):

Both are equivalent and depend on how you have setup the rest of your class.

If you want `this` to be valid within the `callback` method you have 2 options:

**I) Bind the callback in your constructor:**

```
class YourComp extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.callback.bind(this);
  }

  callback() { ... }
}
```

**II) Declare your callback as a lambda (I usually prefer this method as there is no risk of forgetting to bind it)**

```
class YourComp extends React.Component {
  callback = () => { ... your code ... }
}
```

Comment: Sorry to add a follow-up. Actually it's already `arrow function`.

Comment: Then in both cases, the context will be what you expect. Do you have a specific example where it doesnt work as expected ?

Comment: Really sorry for it, it happened once weeks back ago and I cannot locate it now. I will update the post if I meet it again. Thank you, Klugjo

Answer (score 0):

Why at the very beginning I asked this question is that I encountered such kind of *scenarios*:

```
componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
    const { envId, serviceName } = this.props;
    if (envId !== nextProps.envId || serviceName !== nextProps.serviceName) {
      this.reloadService();
    }
  }

reloadService = () => {
    const { envId, serviceName, dispatch } = this.props; // version - 1
    this.setState({ loading: true }, () => {
      const { envId, serviceName, dispatch } = this.props; // version -2
      dispatch(ProdcutActions.fetchServiceDetail(envId, serviceName))
            .then(response => response.data)
            .then((serviceVo) => {
              this.setState({ serviceVo, loading: false });
            });
    });
  }
```

As you can see `reloadService` is used when the `parameters` updated. At very first, I used the **version - 1** since I am planning to use these values later and as a *follow-rule conservative* programmer, I intend to declare the to-be-used variables at the very beginning of the method and then I tumbled into this mess - insidious bug.

As expected I encountered **one-state-behind** case always, because the variables declared will be updated but the callback will refer to the old outdated ones due to **closure** mechanism. But if we directly **extract** the **callback** into a *member method*, it will work normally.

```
componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
    const { envId, serviceName } = this.props;
    if (envId !== nextProps.envId || serviceName !== nextProps.serviceName) {
      this.reloadService();
    }
}

reloadService = () => {
    this.setState({ loading: true }, this.updateServiceDo);
}
updateServiceDo = () => {
    const { envId, serviceName, dispatch } = this.props;
    dispatch(ProdcutActions.fetchServiceDetail(envId, serviceName))
          .then(response => response.data)
          .then((serviceVo) => {
            this.setState({ serviceVo, loading: false });
          });
}
```

Or you can select the **version - 2**, if you're not conservative as I am.